# Acquire/Release semantics reordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization

Based on the C++11 acquire/release semantics, I have the following questions:

Acquire semantics defines: The compiler/CPU should not reorder the reads that happen after the Acquire to happen before the Acquire.
1. But can it reorder the writes that happen after the acquire statement to before the Acquire??

Release semantics defines: The compiler/CPU should not reorder the writes that happen before the Release to happen after the Release.
2. But can it reorder the reads that happen before the Release statement to after the Release??

Example:

```
atomic<int> i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;

i = 0;

j = x;

i = 20;
```

3. Will the compiler/CPU reorder (optimize) the above to the following:

   atomic i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;

   i = 20;

   j = x;
4. But if we use a acquire load, will the compiler/CPU avoid reordering the write to i (i=20) ??

   atomic i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;

   i = 0;

   atomic j = x.load(memory_order_acquire);

   i = 20;

Comment: *"can it reorder the writes that happen after the acquire statement to before the Acquire?"* Generally, yes, under As-If rule, since a race-free conforming program cannot detect this happening. Same for reordering reads around release operation.

Comment: Your examples are difficult to reason about because they confuse initialization of and assignment to an atomic. Initialization of an atomic is not itself an atomic operation (it doesn't have to be - another thread cannot possibly observe or modify an atomic before it's been fully initialized). It's not clear by what mechanisms those atomics get made available to other threads, and at what points in their lifetime.

Comment: I can change my example, since my focus is not on the initialisation.

Comment: Most of the code you posted will be removed by compiler during optimization as dead code, irrelevant of any threading issue. Better post a more practical example.

Comment: As long as you don't show a second thread, that accesses those variables, your "example" isn't of much use. Also, are you aware, that a plain load (as in the first example) has even stronger guarantees than a load with memory_order_aquire?

Answer (score 0):

I think you switched acquire/release semantics..
from [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> memory_order_acquire:     [...] no reads in the
>   current thread can be reordered ***before*** this load.
>
> memory_order_release: [...]   no writes in the current thread can be
>   reordered ***after*** this store.

Regarding your question:

> But can it reorder the writes that happen after the acquire statement
>   to before the Acquire??
>   But can it reorder the reads that happen
>   before the Release statement to after the Release??

Generally, yes, as long as the code effects are carried as they were without reordering, the compiler and the CPU may reorder the instructions to make the program run faster. this is why if strict ordering is required we explicitly use atomics + memory orders and locks.

A general issue that prevents the CPU/Compiler from reordering is a **dependency**, for example, take a look at the following example:

```
int a = atomicA.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
a += 10;
atomicB.store(a,std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

although there are no ordering explicitly stated in the code (relaxed atomics = reorder as you wish), `atomicB` carries dependency of `atomicA` through `a`, and in the case of dependencies - even if no explicit ordering is stated in the code - the execution must flow in the a way that preserve that dependency, in this case, not reorder the stores before the loads.

Comment: You should mention that a dependency in on thread doesn't mean that those accesses appear to happen in the same order from the perspective of another thread (and only there are atomics or release/acquire semantics of any interest to begin with).

Comment: "this is why if strict ordering is required we explicitly use atomics + memory orders" — The OP's code (as it appears right now, anyway) *is* explicitly using atomics and is implicitly using the `seq_cst` memory order. Your answer seems to be written from the assumption that the OP wasn't using atomics at all (like, just raw assignments to `int`), which I don't know if that's how the question used to look or not, but it's definitely not how the question looks anymore.